# Multiplication operation of End(X) with strong topology not continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

> Let $(X, ||\ ||)$ be a normed space. $dim X = \infty$. $L(X)$ is a space of continuous (which is equialent to bounded in a normed space) linear operators with strong topology. Strong topology is defined by zero neighborhoods: $U(x, W) = \{A \in L(X) | Ax \in W\}$, where $x \in X, 0 \in W \in T_X, T_X$ is topology on $X$, and these neighborhoods finite intersections. Convergence $A_n \rightarrow A (A_n, A \in L(X))$ is equialent to convergence $A_n x \rightarrow Ax$ over $X$, $\forall x \in X$. Show that multiplication operation of End(X) (сomposition of operators) isn't continuous.

Comment: I think that you have to define things properly. What is $X$? Is it a Banach space? What is $\text{End}\,(X)$? All endomorphisms, or the bounded ones? What is the strong topology? Pointwise convergence.

Comment: @MartinArgerami thank you for your remark. Question updated.

Comment: Is the considered multiplication the composition?

Comment: @Christian yes.

Comment: @Christian in Hilbert space I can proof that composition of an operator and hermitian self adjoint operator is compact. Using this, I tried to prove by contradiction, but it did not work. Since I can find an operator such as $x_0 = Ax \not\in \hbox{span}(X)$ If it is that exist operator B such that $||Bx_0|| = 1$

Comment: @Pennywise: are you looking for an example of an $X$, or to show that for every $X$ continuity fails?

Comment: @MartinArgerami for every $X$ continuity fails

Comment: by "multiplication operation of $ End(X) $(сomposition of operators) isn't continuous" do you mean for each $u\in L(X)$, the map $$M_u:L(X)\to L(X), v\mapsto u\circ v$$ isn't strongly continuous?

Comment: @C.Ding I think yes

Comment: I assume the question refers to **joint** strong continuity. Multiplication by a fixed elements is trivially strongly continuous.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I think so yes.